# d3.js. How to make map full width?

Tags: d3.js, topojson

Code available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zeleniy/zksg1yo4/). Map looks like full width, but not at all. There is some indents at the top and left and right sides. All examples of d3.js maps use some strange magic numbers in [scale method](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#scale). I try use such numbers from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14299083), but looks like it is not true for my case. So what is true way to scale map? I want to make it full width without any indents on any screen.

```
var body = d3.select("body").node().getBoundingClientRect();

var coef = 640 / 360;

var width = body.width;
var height = width / coef;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)

var projection = d3.geo.equirectangular()
  .rotate([-180, 0])
  .scale(width / 640 * 100)
  .translate([width / 2, height / 2])

var path = d3.geo.path()
  .projection(projection);


d3.json("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/20g0rtglh9xawb8/world-50m.json?dl=1", function(error, world) {
  svg.append("path")
    .datum(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.land))
    .attr("d", path);
});
```

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492284/center-a-map-in-d3-given-a-geojson-object)?

Comment: May be, but i do not know what is `json` variable in example you provide. I use standard `world-50m.json` data file from topojson package. So if i provide `world` variable to path.bounds() method i gave array with infinities...

Comment: Well, your fiddle doesn't work for me, so I'm not sure what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Try to open it at Firefox

Comment: Right, that seems to work. So the space at the top and bottom is simply because of the aspect ratio and the left and right margins because of the margins of the `body` element.

Comment: No, see CSS section of fiddle, i set margin to zero

Comment: Any margins you see will be a result of the scale factor that you set.

Comment: Exactly this i asked in this topic - how to pick right scale factor for my example to remove margins :)

Comment: And that's exactly what the question I've linked to in my first comment tells you :)

Comment: Yes, i know it, but i just can't apply it to my code

Comment: I think all you need to do is replace `json` with `topojson.feature(world, world.objects.land)`.

Comment: Yes, you're right! Thank you very much! But this is only solve problem of margins from left and right. To remove margin from top i change coef from 640 / 360 to 640 / 309. Magic numbers still here. There is new [fiddle without margins](http://jsfiddle.net/zeleniy/1zs9vdpg/)

Comment: You would be distorting the map if you want it to stretch to the full window.

Comment: Is your issue fixed meanwhile?